# How to draw polylines and polygons on layout using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, drawing

I've been searching some example about how to draw polylines and polygons on the map composer using PyQGIS, but I couldn't find anything.
Could someone show me some code to learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are stuck, you should look at [QGIS API documentation](https://www.qgis.org/api/), [PyQGIS documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/) and Python tests directory from QGIS repository e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/tests/src/python

For the first two links for your use cases, you should look at classes containing `QgsLayout` string (by doing a textual search)

You may wonder how I've guessed I should look at `QgsLayoutItemPolygon` or `QgsLayoutItemPolyline`? I've drawn manually the line and the polygon and selected them individually in the layout. Then, I've run the 4 first lines from below recipe in the QGIS Python console to know which class was involved. The other parts are mainly standalone version of the tests directory for your purpose.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('demo') # Use your layout name instead of demo
layout.selectedLayoutItems()

# Recipe from layout Polygon
# Mainly borrowed from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayoutpolygon.py
polygon1 = QPolygonF()
polygon1.append(QPointF(0.0, 0.0))
polygon1.append(QPointF(100.0, 0.0))
polygon1.append(QPointF(200.0, 100.0))
polygon1.append(QPointF(100.0, 200.0))

layoutItemPolygon = QgsLayoutItemPolygon(polygon1, layout)
layout.addLayoutItem(layoutItemPolygon)

# Recipe from layout Polyline
# Mainly borrowed from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_qgslayoutpolyline.py
polygon2 = QPolygonF()
polygon2.append(QPointF(50.0, 150.0))
polygon2.append(QPointF(150.0, 80.0))
polygon2.append(QPointF(250.0, 100.0))
polygon2.append(QPointF(10.0, 200.0))

layoutItemPolyline = QgsLayoutItemPolyline(polygon2, layout)
layout.addLayoutItem(layoutItemPolyline)
```

Comment: Thats just what i needed!
I thank you very much for the advice, I will always keep it in mind. I'm really new to pyqgis development and you've given me a big push.